# Read data from csv file to query oracle developer database

Tags: database, oracle

First, I am not able to write to the database. I can only read the data stored in the database.

I have a file that I want to use to help me query a database. I have thousands of IDs I need to query information for.

Is there a way that I can read the IDs and other identifying information to query the database without having to query each one individually?

Without being too specific a simplified version of the query I would have to run:

Select publicID 1 and publicID 2 from customer table
Where ID = '123' and firstname = 'Joe' and lastname = 'Bob'

Is there a way that I could read one row at a time on a csv file that would have the data for the where statement? It would just cycle through the csv file and provide an output with the needed values.

So something like

Select publicID 1 and publicID 2 from customer table
Where ID = column 1 row 2 and firstname = column 2 row 2  and lastname = column 3 row 2

Then it would iterate all the way to the end of the file.

Comment: Yes there's a way. You already covered it in your last paragraphs. Since you haven't specified which language you're using your own pseudo-code will cover it.

Comment: You may use `where (col1, col2, col3) in ( (val1, val2, val3), ....)` and generate as much tuples as you need with any programming language or spreadsheet app